# Static files not working in Django development

Tags: static-files, django-1.8

I'm trying to follow the section in the Django docs called [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/).  I am interested in finding out:

1. What I am doing wrong.
2. Or, what is wrong with the Django docs.

1) ***Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS.***

In the default `settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',  #<****HERE*****
)
```

2) ***In your settings file, define STATIC_URL***, for example:   `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

In the default `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

3) ***In your templates, either hardcode the url like*** `/static/my_app/myexample.jpg`

In mysite2/mysite2/views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('''

        <h2>Hello</h2>
        <img src="/static/mysite2/Aerial03.jpg">


    ''')
```

4) ***Store your static files in a folder called static in your app. For example:*** `my_app/static/my_app/myimage.jpg`.

Here is my directory structure:

```
(django186p34)~/django_projects$ tree mysite2

mysite2
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── mysite2
    ├── __init__.py

    ├── settings.py
    ├── static           #<****HERE*****
    │   └── mysite2
    │       └── Aerial03.jpg
    ├── urls.py
    ├── views.py
    └── wsgi.py

4 directories, 13 files
```

But after starting the server:

```
(django186p34)~/django_projects/mysite2$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 26, 2015 - 02:44:57
Django version 1.8.6, using settings 'mysite2.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

And then navigating in my browser to:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

I see the text:

```
Hello
```

but the image is not found:

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 `http://localhost:8000/static/mysite2/Aerial03.jpg`

I've tried many combinations of urls in my html and nothing works.

Here is `settings.py` in its entirety(I made no changes):

```
"""
Django settings for mysite2 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'pmaup3%)m09cs2goldduw2iogso%(#8cz0s-zmr%*e'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite2.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed things:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite2',  #<*****HERE*****
)
```

---

And if you organize things so that you have apps inside your project, e.g.:

```
(django186p34)~/django_projects$ tree mysite3
mysite3
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── myapp
│   ├── __init__.py

│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   

│   │    
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── myapp
│   │       └── Aerial03.jpg
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── mysite3
    ├── __init__.py

    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py

8 directories, 24 files
```

Then in `settings.py` add your app name to `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',  #<*****HERE*****
)
```

Everything else in the default `settings.py` stays the same.  However, the urls are different:

mysite3/mysite3/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

mysite3/myapp/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

And in your browser, the url becomes:

```
http://localhost:8000/myapp/
```

myapp/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('''

        <h2>Hello</h2>
        <img src="/static/myapp/Aerial03.jpg">


    ''')
```